# Cannot access port opened in WSL from windows browser or other app

Tags: windows, tcp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run a server from my WSL environment, the browser or postman installed in Windows is unable to hit it. Chrome responds with `localhost refused to connect` but if I were to `curl localhost:3000` from the linux command line it succeeds.

I tried adding a rule to allow tcp connections to localhost: in the windows defender firewall with advanced security app:
[image]

What is more perplexing is that this only happens occasionally! If I restart and restart the server, it seems okay... or not. I've tried a couple server-running applications to confirm that this isn't just an issue with the code that I am trying to run.